# Can't get rid of black pixel underneath slideshow

Tags: slider, slideshow, flexslider, singlepage

On [this website](http://www.alliedouglass.com/20120521_index.html), I got a problem: Black pixel located bottom-left to the homepage flexslider image carousel.

I can't seem to get rid of it, however it seems to be associated with the `ul`.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your stylesheet and change:

```
.slides:after {
 clear: both;
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
}
```

into:

```
.slides:after {
 clear: both;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
}
```

You should also have a look at the [css content property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)